# Cassandra data stax driver update 4.4 query timeout issues

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

our application was recently upgraded to cassandra datastax driver 4.4.X. Earlier it was on version 3.3. After the upgrade we noticed quite a lot of timeout issues for ex:

1. init query timeout
2. session query timeout
3. control connection timeout..
4. and other timeout parameters defaulted in reference.conf

Earlier this used to work with default parameter but after the upgrade we need to default this to > 5 seconds.

Have any one faced similar issue after the upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade to at least Java driver 4.8 (better to 4.9) - previously timeouts were too aggressive (0.5 seconds), in 4.8 it was increased to 5 seconds (by fix of [JAVA-2841](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2841)).

Or you can just override corresponding parameters in the `application.conf` file.

Comment: I have added below in application.conf under resources folder but it is not working for me.     init-query-timeout = 30 seconds
 timeout = 30 seconds
 connect-timeout = 30 seconds

Comment: I am not understanding how to upgrade java driver to 4.9 while its version is managed by spring boot dependency itself, is there any workaround to override it?

Comment: you can exclude dependency from the spring-boot, and explicitly include it into your project definition