# Spring boot data Cassandra throws com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am upgrading my application using spring-data-cassandra, from 2.X to 3.X. I am using spring boot's default CassandraAutoConfiguration to connect to Cassandra.

With spring data Cassandra 2.x, giving values to below Cassandra application properties I am able to connect to my cluster and execute queries in my dao using cassandraTemplate

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=contactpoint1,contactpoint2,contactpoint3,contactpoint4
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=<keyspace name>
spring.data.cassandra.cluster-name=<cluster name>
spring.data.cassandra.username=<username>
spring.data.cassandra.password=<password>
```

spring.data.cassandra.consistency-level=one
spring.data.cassandra.fetch-size=100

But with spring data cassandra 3.x, since the application properties have changed due to upgrade of datastax drive to version 4.X internally. I am giving below properties in my application properties.

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=contactpoint1,contactpoint2,contactpoint3,contactpoint4
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=<keyspace name>
spring.data.cassandra.session-name=<session name>
spring.data.cassandra.username=<username>
spring.data.cassandra.password=<password>
spring.data.cassandra.request.consistency=local_one
spring.data.cassandra.request.page-size=100
spring.data.cassandra.connection.init-query-timeout=2000ms
```

So while running by project when spring boot auto configure tries to connect to cassandra and I am getting below error:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.peers' timed out after PT0.5S
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:612) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraSession(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:74) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Spring boot version i am using is 2.3.3.RELEASE. Spring data cassandra and datastax driver version are the ones which come with this spring boot release.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027079/cassandra-data-stax-driver-update-4-4-query-timeout-issues/64027977#64027977

Answer (score 0):

Add `@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "pacakage.names")` over the spring boot main class file